# Ubuntu 18.04 No Sound after reboot until I run pactl load-module command?

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa

Ever since I upgraded to 18.04 I have had problems with the system not detecting my sound card after a reboot.  "Dummy Output" is the Sound output and I have no sound.

I have tried many posted problem solutions but none have really worked..

After a reboot I now run the command:

```
pactl load-module module-detect
```

Then the Sound Settings show "Builtin Audio Analog Stereo" as the output and everything is fine... 
UNTIL I reboot again...

Is there anything I can do so that the sound card will be correctly detected after a reboot, without having to manually run the pactl command?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the command in your Startup Applications.

To do that, press <kbd>Super</kbd> to open the Activities Overview and search for Startup Applications (no need to type the whole name, the first few letters will be enough). Then click *Add* and enter a name for your startup command, the command and a comment (if you wish), as shown in the following screenshot.

[image: Startup applications]

The command should now run automatically after rebooting and your sound output should be the correct one.

Comment: Thanks!   I'd thought of trying something like that.  My concern would be that this seems like an ok workaround, but maybe there is something else that I don't have setup correctly that is causing the problem, and maybe that should be fixed?